# Not getting different class names while iterating

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I am having a v-for loop in my vuejs application. i want each span to have a different class name. For example .spa0, .spa1, .spa3..... How do I do it using index in v-for loop?

I tried something like this:

```
 :class="`spa${index}`"
```

Some of my code is:

```
<div>
<span v-for="(t, index) in table_data" :class="`spa${index}`">{{t}}</span>
</div>
```

I expect each span to have a different class.

Comment: Could you share the data structure of `table_data` ?

Comment: table_data: {
            type: 'LDAP',
            des: 'LDAP for Demo - Do not edit or delete this App',
            api: 'show token',
            scim: 'http://cloud.kapstonellc.com:8082/scim/v2/10VN44ZN',
            endis: true,
            act: true
          },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `table_data` is like this as you stated in the comments:

```
{
  type: 'LDAP',
  des: 'LDAP for Demo - Do not edit or delete this App',
  api: 'show token',
  scim: 'cloud.kapstonellc.com:8082/scim/v2/10VN44ZN',
  endis: true,
  act: true
}
```

You should probably iterate over `table_data` keys instead:

```
<div>
  <span v-for="(key, index) in Object.keys(table_data)" :class="`spa${index}`">
    {{ table_data[key] }}
  </span>
</div>
```